# Regex match all href in string, except if containing a word

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match all `href` within a string, but exclude (I believe using negative lookahead) when the href contains a specific text, such as `login`, for example:

```js
const str = `This is some a string <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a> and this is another that should not be found <a href="https://www.google.com/login">login</a>`

const match = str.match(/href="(.*?)"/g)

console.log(match)
```

This matches all of the `href`, but doesn't factor in the exclusion of `login` being found in one.  I've tried a few different variations, but really haven't gotten anywhere.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex which does a negative look behind just before the quote,

```
href="(.*?)(?<!login)"
```

Demo,

https://regex101.com/r/15DwZE/1

Edit 1:
As fourth bird pointed out that above regex may not work in general and instead of coming up with a complicated regex that can cover all possibilities of login appearance in url to be rejected, here is a javascript solution.

```js
var myString = 'This is some a string <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a> and this is another that should not be found <a href="https://www.google.com/login">login</a>';
var myRegexp = /href="(.*?)"/g;
match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
while (match != null) {
    if (match[1].indexOf('login') == -1) {
        console.log(match[1]);
    }
  match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
}
```

Comment: This looks great.  Thank you

Comment: Note that not all browsers support negative look behind.

Comment: @dzm If the href should not contain login, then this will still match `<a href="https://www.google.com/login/test">test</a>`. Also for example this is what will be matched when adding another link [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gs8rfJ/1)

Comment: @Thefourthbird: You're right. A pure regex solution for covering all cases would've been non-trivial and that was just my little effort to cover the case OP had. Anyway, I have extended OP's solution to achieve same and updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this without a regex using a [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and use for example [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if href contains your string.

```js
let parser = new DOMParser();
let html = `This is some a string <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a> and this is another that should not be found <a href="https://www.google.com/login">login</a>`;
let doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
let anchors = doc.querySelectorAll("a");
anchors.forEach(a => {
  if (!a.href.includes("login")) {
    console.log(a.href);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have temporary HTML node and get all `<a>` tags from it. Then filter by href. Sample code:

```
const str = `This is some a string <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a> and this is another that should not be found <a href="https://www.google.com/login">login</a>`;
const d = document.createElement('div');
d.innerHTML = str;
Array.from(d.getElementsByTagName("a")).filter(a => !/login/.test(a.href))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to do that

```
/<[\w:]+(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\shref\s*=\s*(?:(['"])(?:(?!\1|login)[\S\s])*\1))\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+>/
```

https://regex101.com/r/LEQL7h/1

More info

```
 < [\w:]+               # Any tag
 (?= \s )
 (?=                    # Asserttion (a pseudo atomic group)
      (?: [^>"'] | " [^"]* " | ' [^']* ' )*?
      \s href \s* = \s*      # href attribute
      (?:
           ( ['"] )               # (1), Quote
           (?:
                (?! \1 | login )       # href cnnot contain login
                [\S\s] 
           )*
           \1 
      )
 )
                        # Have href that does not contain login, match the rest of tag
 \s+ 
 (?: " [\S\s]*? " | ' [\S\s]*? ' | [^>]*? )+

 >
```